# Docker block IP

Tags: docker, geolocation, ip2location

I tried to use docker in our network but it seems like they block countries.

> nSince Docker is a US company, we must comply with US export control regulations. In an effort to comply with these, we now block all IP addresses that are located in Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Republic of Crimea, Sudan, and Syria. If you are not in one of these cities, countries, or regions and are blocked, please reach out to https://support.docker.com\n\n\n"
> Unable to find image 'kadirahq/meteord:latest' locally
> docker: Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "
>
> ## 403 Forbidden
>
> \nSince Docker is a US company, we must comply with US export control regulations. In an effort to comply with these, we now block all IP addresses that are located in Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Republic of Crimea, Sudan, and Syria. If you are not in one of these cities, countries, or regions and are blocked, please reach out to https://support.docker.com\n\n\n".
> See 'docker run --help'.

My country is not listed under the blocked countries and seems maybe they have a bad IP correction.

Someone know which IP correction service they use? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are lived in restricted locations like IRAN, docker not work and may generate related message.

Here is the message

> Since Docker is a US company, we must comply with US export control regulations. In an effort to comply with these, we now block all IP addresses that are located in Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Republic of Crimea, Sudan, and Syria. If you are not in one of these cities, countries, or regions and are blocked, please reach out to https://support.docker.com\n\n\n". See 'docker run --help

As * docker company restricted IRAN we have two options.

### Use Mirror registry

Using mirror instead of default docker registry

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
        "registry-mirrors": ["https://registry.docker.ir"]
}

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

If its not work use proxy for docker

### Set proxy

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.5.35:8119"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.5.35:8119"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.example.com,.corp"


$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```